# Conditional statement to target specific "Engravings" category for function that adds field to Woocommerce product pages

Tags: wordpress, text, woocommerce, field, product

I appreciate Umairs latest answer on this: [How do I add a field on the WooCommerce product page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633761/how-do-i-add-a-field-on-the-woocommerce-product-page)

In my case I'm looking to add a statement to only display this text field on products within a "engravings" category I have created.   It's currently set and displays globally for all types of products.

Thanks for your help.

```js
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button(  ) 
{
    // make action magic happen here...

    echo "<input type='text' name='engrave-text' id='engrave-text' placeholder='Your Engraving Text'>";
};

// add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 10, 0 );


function engrave_text_validation() { 
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['engrave-text'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a Name for Engraving', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'engrave_text_validation', 10, 3 );


function save_engrave_text_field( $cart_item_key, $product_id = null, $quantity= null, $variation_id= null, $variation= null ) {
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['engrave-text'] ) ) {
        WC()->session->set( $cart_item_key.'_engrave_text', $_REQUEST['engrave-text'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'save_engrave_text_field', 1, 5 );

function render_meta_on_cart_item( $title = null, $cart_item = null, $cart_item_key = null ) {
    if( $cart_item_key && WC()->session->__isset( $cart_item_key.'_engrave_text' ) ) {
        echo $title. '<dl class="">
                 <dt class="">Engrave Text : </dt>
                 <dd class=""><p>'. WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_engrave_text') .'</p></dd>         
              </dl>';
    }else {
        echo $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'render_meta_on_cart_item', 1, 3 );

function render_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item( $quantity = null, $cart_item = null, $cart_item_key = null ) {
    if( $cart_item_key && WC()->session->__isset( $cart_item_key.'_engrave_text' ) ) {
        echo $quantity. '<dl class="">
                 <dt class="">Engrave Text: </dt>
                 <dd class=""><p>'. WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_engrave_text') .'</p></dd>
              </dl>';
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'render_meta_on_checkout_order_review_item', 1, 3 );

function engrave_text_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( WC()->session->__isset( $cart_item_key.'_engrave_text' ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "Engrave Text", WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_engrave_text') );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'engrave_text_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );

function engrave_force_individual_cart_items($cart_item_data, $product_id)
{
    $unique_cart_item_key = md5( microtime().rand() );
    $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data','engrave_force_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Can you not do this with [Product Add-ons](https://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/)?

Comment: I can. My question is the ability of modifying this.  I assume it's better served to run as a plugin and not within functions.php  If It's going to need to get the posts terms and if matches the category etc.   I'd like to still be able to understand for a learning.       //Do something if a specific array value exists within a post
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_features', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
echo $term_single->slug; //do something here
}

Comment: With product add-ons you create a global add-on and apply it to a particular category. Sorry, I usually suggest a plugin when a new user asks how to do something that is exactly covered by a plugin. If you want to keep using your custom code, but adapt it only for certain categories then you should try the [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function.

Comment: I had a similar issue (showing content conditionally on invoice based on category). Maybe you can adapt my solution to your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096119/woocommerce-email-invoice-conditional-policies-based-on-product-category

Comment: Thanks helgatheviking, correct, it's better served through the plugin. Jeff Cohan, thanks yes I'm familiar using has term wasn't sure exactly where it would be entered into this engraving. It's dangerous either way shooting up the load time running all of this in functions.php outside of the natural "loop".